# Can you create a bottom row in SQL for custom calculations?

Tags: sql

I need to create a bottom row in sql that will have regular averages for columns as well as take in the sum of two columns and calculate a weighted average for some specific columns. Is this possible?

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Comment: I too have seen this thing

Comment: A bottom row on a report? What database?

Answer (score 0):

You can compute an average one or more columns with a query like:

```
SELECT AVG(mycol1), AVG(mycol2) FROM mytable
```

You can compute a sum of multiple columns:

```
SELECT SUM(mycol1)+ SUM(mycol2) AS mytotal FROM mytable
```

You can weight the column sums:

```
SELECT 2*SUM(mycol1)+ 3*SUM(mycol2) AS mytotal FROM mytable
```

Or perform more complex operations on those SUM() or AVG() results, but think of these results as separate from the original column data, not like a "bottom row" in a spreadsheet calculation.

Comment: I guess you could make a view of original data and a summary row using "UNION" ?